# Typescript index.d.ts declaration for deeply nested function in an npm package

Tags: typescript, npm, declaration

Unfortunately, `@types/rickshaw` seems to be empty, so I have to make my own declaration file. This is my current one:

```
declare module 'rickshaw' {
    export class Graph {
        constructor(obj: any);
        render: any;
    }
}
```

Which lets me use the methods `render` and create a new instance perfectly fine. But now I'm looking to declare a deeply nested method from rickshaw. My current declaration won't let me use this, with the error:

```
Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time({graph: newGraph})
(25,41): Property 'Axis' does not exist on type 'typeof Graph'.
```

I checked the method's source code and it looks like this

```
Rickshaw.namespace('Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time');

Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time = function(args) {
 //...
}
```

How can I declare `Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time`?

edit: Here is my new declaration file. I'm now running into
`'new' expression, whose target lacks a constructor signature implicitly has an any type`

```
interface TimeArgs {
    graph: typeof Graph;
    ticksTreatment: string;
}

interface AxisInterface {
    Time: (args: TimeArgs) => void;
}

export class Graph {
    constructor(obj: any);
    render: any;
    static Axis: AxisInterface;
}
```

I tried to fix it by stating `tyepof Graph`, because the `graph` argument in `Time` is an instance of the `new Rickshaw.Graph` object, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with `rickshaw` but you've already added `Graph`, now you can add `Axis` inside `Graph` and then add `Time` inside `Axis`:

```
declare module 'rickshaw' {
    interface TimeArgs {
        graph: any;
    }
    interface AxisInterface {
        Time: (args: TimeArgs) => void;
    }
    export class Graph {
        constructor(obj: any);
        render: any;
        static Axis: AxisInterface;
    }
}
```

And add any other types/interfaces as you see fit.

Comment: No problem and thanks for the correction. I'm knee deep in something else at the moment so I never got the chance to run it :)

Comment: I'm now running into another problem. Question is updated